# What type of wood was Haman's gallows?

Tags: torah-study, purim

There are certainly different explanations of where Haman found a massive beam of wood to construct his gallows, but what TYPE of wood was it?

Pirkei D'Rabbi ELiezer [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_DeRabbi_Eliezer.50.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en#:%7E:text=There%20is%20a%20tree%20in%20Haman%27s%20house%20(taken)%20from%20the%20Holy%20of%20Holies%2C%20fifty%20cubits%20high) says it was taken from the Kodesh Hakodashim - maybe this helps in knowing what type of wood it was?

Midrash Talpiyot mentions that it was made from the Eitz Hadas. - does anyone know what type of wood that was?

(I am looking for something besides using the idea that it was from the ark and therefore presumed to be gopher wood)

If you enjoy this question and discussion, please up-vote it.

Comment: Why do you ask?

Comment: Mostly to further my learning and understanding. But also i am trying to see if anyone knows of any opinios or ways off deducing that the wood was made of Acacia wood.

Comment: The Midrash famously says it was from Noach's ark - why would you think differently?

Comment: Different midrashim have different sources of where it came from (see Pirkei Drabbi Eliezer in the question above)

Comment: @TheTargum when writing the answer, your most recent edit wasn't effective yet, so I included sources about gopher wood aka cedar wood.

Comment: If it was from Kodesh Hakodashim then it was likely made from a Lebanese cedar.

Comment: @Harel13 what is your understanding for thinking that?

Comment: Because the Temple was built from ארזי הלבנון (The aforementioned cedars).

Comment: Who said Haman was hanged?  https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/90079/capital-punishment-in-persia

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/128525/27180

Answer (score 2):

[Yalkut Shimoni](https://www.sefaria.org/Yalkut_Shimoni_on_Nach.1059.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) explains that there was a fury debate between the trees and that a specific tree was chosen that was fifty cubits high, so that everyone could see the tree from afar. The Yalkut Shimoni here mentions the cedar tree also.

According to the Midrash in Esther Rabbah (source still seeking, chapter 9), the **thorn-tree** was used for the gallows.

There are also sources that say that the **wood was from the tree of knowledge** [(see: Haman's tree by Rabbi Heschel Greenberg)](http://www.chabadnj.org/page.asp?pageID=%7BF416D5A3-CEF8-4925-A0EE-B41799D3B378%7D&displayAll=1)

The [Yalkut Shimoni](https://www.sefaria.org/Yalkut_Shimoni_on_Torah.256.1?vhe=Yalkut_Shimoni_on_Torah&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) writes that the wood, used for the gallows, was originally from the Ark of Noah.

> ונטל נסר א' מתבתו של נח שעשה הקב"ה זכרון לעולם שידעו דורות עולם שהביא מבול לעולם שכן כתיב זכר עשה לנפלאותיו וכן כשנהפכו סדום ועמורה כתיב ותבט אשתו מאחריו ועד עכשיו היא עומדת נציב מלח. למה זכר עשה לנפלאותיו שיהיו הדורות מתנין שבחו של הקב"ה

If we look back to the point where G-d instructs Noah to build the ark, G-d [instructs](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.6.14?ven=The_Contemporary_Torah,_Jewish_Publication_Society,_2006&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) Noah to build it from Gopher wood:

> Make yourself an ark of gopher wood; make it an ark with compartments,
> and cover it inside and out with pitch.

The [Onkelos](https://www.sefaria.org/Onkelos_Genesis.6.14?vhe=Targum_Onkelos,_vocalized_according_to_the_Yemenite_Taj_&lang=bi&lookup=%D7%93%D6%B0%D6%BC%D7%90%D6%B8%D7%A2%D6%B4%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%93%D6%B0%D6%BC%D7%A7%D6%B7%D7%93%D6%B0%D7%A8%D7%95%D6%B9%D7%A1&with=Lexicon&lang2=en) says that gopher wood can also read as cedar wood דְּאָעִין דְּקַדְרוֹס:

> Make for yourself an ark of cedar wood. Make the ark into compartments and caulk the inside and outside with tar.

See also the [Radak (ad loc.)](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.6.14?lang=bi&with=Radak&lang2=en).

According to the [Rabbeinu Bahya](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.6.14?ven=The_Contemporary_Torah,_Jewish_Publication_Society,_2006&lang=bi&with=Rabbeinu%20Bahya&lang2=en), it was light-weight kind of wood
and well-known to the people.

So, you ask what kind of wood it was. Well, if we build unto the words of the Yalkut Shimoni, it was the same wood as the Ark of Noah's was. Therefore, according to Onkelos, **it was cedar wood.** According to the posuk itself, it was gopher wood.

Comment: he wants to avoid the approach that it came from the Ark and was gopher wood

Comment: when writing the answer, your most recent edit wasn't effective yet, so I included sources about gopher wood aka cedar wood.

Comment: Thank you Reb Shmuel for this detailed answer. I am trying to avoid (for purposes of this conversation) the notion that it was gopher wood from the ark.

Comment: The Onkelos in my answer says it was cedar.