# Haman's gallow came from the kodesh hakodashim

Tags: beis-hamikdash, purim, haman

Although there are a number of sources of where Haman had found a beam 50 cubits tall to use as a gallows, some say it was a beam from the teyva, some say it was a thorny tree etc but, there is an interesting anecdote found [here in Pirkei D'Rabbi Eliezer](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_DeRabbi_Eliezer.50.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en#:%7E:text=There%20is%20a%20tree%20in%20Haman%27s%20house%20(taken)%20from%20the%20Holy%20of%20Holies%2C%20fifty%20cubits%20high:%7E:text=%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A8%20%D7%9C%D7%95%20%D7%90%D7%93%D7%A0%D7%99%20%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%9A%20%D7%99%D7%A9%20%D7%A2%D7%A5%20%D7%91%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA%D7%95%20%D7%A9%D7%9C%20%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%9F%20%D7%9E%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA%20%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%A9%D7%99%20%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9D%2C) that says the beam was actually from the kodesh hakodashim.

Is this mentioned or referenced anywhere else?

Why would there be such a beam in the kodesh hakodashim?

Lastly, if this is allegorical, what is the lesson to be learned?

Comment: Wasn't this asked recently?

Comment: Similair, although not a duplicate: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/135303/27180

Comment: @Dov Previously i had asked what type of wood the gallows were made of (https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/135303/what-type-of-wood-was-hamans-gallows) Our current question is trying to delve more into the idea that the gallows was from the kodeh hakodashim

Comment: "Why would there be such a beam in the kodesh hakodashim?" I don't understand why this is a question. Why wouldn't there have been beams utilized in its construction?

Comment: Also, tangentially related is that beams from the Second Temple were likely re-used in Al-Aqsa: https://www.timesofisrael.com/did-ancient-beams-discarded-in-old-city-come-from-first-and-second-temples/

Comment: @Deuteronomy 50 cubits is a very large beam, the actual Kodesh Hakodashim wasnt so huge.

Comment: @TheTargum Yes it is, but if I recall correctly combined with the 'aliyah (upper storey/attic) the Qodesh ha-Qodoshim would have been 100 amoth. I don't think it is inconceivable that there were beams that were continuous from the level of the Qodesh ha-Qodoshim to and through the upper storey... if it is, then there is another issue here, not why was there a beam of 50 amoth there but rather how such was even possible.

Comment: @Deuteronomy thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The 50 cubits of wood are mentioned in the Book of Kings chapter 7 when Shlomo haMelech built the Temple. Maybe it comes to teach that when the evil forces steal the Kedusha, take it to their dominion, in the end of the day- it will not only come back to Kedusha but will ultimatley destroy the forces of evil in the very act of coming back.

Comment: Nice chiddush!!

Comment: Your answer is kinda discussed in [this article](http://www.chabadnj.org/page.asp?pageID=%7BF416D5A3-CEF8-4925-A0EE-B41799D3B378%7D&displayAll=1).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Targum Simcha Tu B'Shvat]

From what is mentioned in the Targum Simcha on Tu B'Shvat, he does cite some more sources that mention the gallows being sourced from the Beis Hamikdash, he also hypothesized on when it would have been possible or likely for Haman to have gotten the beam from the Har Habayis.

As to the question of why there was such a beam in that location, in the explanation of the Targum Simcha, both times (mentioned) that it was possible for Haman to be on the Har Habayis had been after the churban, and in my assumption, its possible that among the ruble and destruction there was a beam that satisfied his criteria